# Problems configuring mybatis-spring in Red5

Tags: eclipse, spring, red5, mybatis

All,

I'm trying to configure MyBatis in an application running under Red5 server. I created an additional spring config file `red5-ibatis.xml` under `WEB-INF` which has these beans configured (as described in mybatis-spring user guide):

```
<bean id="hsqldbDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:./db/hsqldb/testdb" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="hsqldbDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="userMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="test.mappers.UserMapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

When I run the server with the app deployed I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Launcher:/testapp" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userMapper' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-ibatis.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean' to required type 'org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory' for property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean] to required type [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory] for property 'sqlSessionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader$1.run(TomcatLoader.java:594)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean' to required type 'org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory' for property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean] to required type [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory] for property 'sqlSessionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:462)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:499)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean] to required type [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory] for property 'sqlSessionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:231)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:447)
    ... 15 more
```

I'm not sure, but it looks like Spring doesn't see that the `SqlSessionFactoryBean` implements the `FactoryBean` interface and so cannot find the way to convert it to `SqlSessionFactory`?

Anyway, any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, seems like I got it solved. Looks like I had all the Spring jars in my app `WEB-INF/lib` directory, which probably was bad because they are also in Red5 `lib` folder, so they were duplicated. After messing with my `ivy.xml` dependencies configuration and my Eclipse project deployment assembly settings, it started working.

Basically I had to remove standard `Libraries/ivy.xml [*]` from my Eclipse project and add two separate ones, which in my case were: `ivy.xml [runtime]` and `ivy.xml [compile]`. Then in my Eclipse project properties, in "deployment assembly" settings I chose to only deploy the dependecies from `ivy.xml [runtime]`, which didn't contain Spring libraries.

No more exceptions.